# EXCEL: Lookup a value and the minimum date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an issue with excel. My data is located in 2 different spread sheets.

The sheets are login and events:

**LOGIN**

user_id  (COL A)

signup_date (COL B)

**EVENTS**

user_id (COL A)

end_date (COL B)

revenue (COL C)

I am trying to find the average days from a user signing up to their first event ending.
In trying to match the user ids, I have the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
=MIN(IF(A2=Events!$A$2:$A$12282,(Events!B$2:B$12282)-B2))
```

In this case, for each user in login, i am trying to find the corresponding dates in Events that match with that user. Then I am trying to find the difference in dates and find the minimum one in the array, but it is giving the max value instead and/or not working. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Cross posted [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18517642/1578604).

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a single cell to a range in the way you have:

```
IF(A2=Events!$A$2:$A$12282...
```

You could try a lookup function instead.

Comment: You actually can with Array formulas. His application may not work here, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: in the third column of the first sheet type this formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A$2,Events!A$2:A$12282,1,0)
```

This should put the corresponding end_date value of the user in A2. Beware, this would work iff there is only one end date for every user.

If this was what you were looking for, just drag the formula to fill in all the values.

Now on the fourth column you could do something like

```
=C$2-B$2
```

Again, drag the formula to fill in all the missing values.

Now you should have all the calculations ready, and you should just need to do

```
=MIN(D2:D12282)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Login sheet I would add one more column `days_to_first_event`. And in C2 add the following array formula (press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to set it)

```
=MIN(IF(tbl_events[user_id]=A2,tbl_events[end_date]))-B2
```

This finds the earliest `end_date` for the `user_id` on the `Events` sheet, then subtracts the user's `signup_date`. (I've formatted them as a table called `tbl_events` but you can substitute for your range)

Then you can average based on positive values, as anything negative would mean that they have not completed an event yet. Using this formula

```
=SUMIF(C:C,">=0")/COUNTIF(C:C,">=0")
```

It's possible to contain all of that in one formula, but I can't wrap my brain around that this morning.